# Books of algebraic number theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation

I am learning algebraic number theory, the exercises are so hard for me, could you please recommend me a book with answers? Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think a book with answers will help you very much. Sure, you'll probably pick up some tricks, but in the long run I think it is better if you figure out why the exercises are so hard for you, it might be that you lack some knowledge or misunderstand some concept. Also, if you are stuck, you can also post your attempt and look for help on this forum. I think you'll benefit more from this strategy.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks!

Comment: @Student You are right, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Murty & Esmonde's *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory* (available [here](http://148.206.53.84/tesiuami/S_pdfs/Problems%20in%20Algebraic%20Number%20Theory.pdf) as a pdf) is an excellent source of problems with solutions. However, as someone pointed out in the comments, looking up a solution to a problem is helpful only after you have worked on it yourself for a sufficient amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Reid's book from 1910(-ish) gives a very slow introduction.  I don't think it has answers, but it has almost everything worked out in the text.  If you don't mind the stilted, 100-year-old language, you mind find it useful.  I see it's on Amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Theory-Algebraic-Numbers/dp/1110380461](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1110380461)

But I know there are scans of it online.